# Is there any way to test an anonymous inner class using junit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, anonymous-class

I have the following class that I would like to test. Having to test an anonymous inner class is proving to be very difficult. Any help would be appreciated.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomErrorConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ErrorAttributes errorAttributes() {
        return new DefaultErrorAttributes() {

            @Override
            public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(RequestAttributes requestAttributes,
                    boolean includeStackTrace) {
                Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, includeStackTrace);
                errorAttributes.remove("timestamp");
                errorAttributes.remove("status");
                errorAttributes.remove("exception");
                errorAttributes.remove("path");
                if (errorAttributes.containsKey("error") && errorAttributes.containsKey("message")) {
                    Map<String, Object> attr = new HashMap<>();
                    attr.put("message", errorAttributes.get("message"));
                    return attr;
                }
                return errorAttributes;
            }

        };
    }

}
```

Comment: why cannot you just create a static class inside CustomErrorConfiguration and test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the minimum needed to test your inner class:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class BeanTest {

    @Autowired
    ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

    @Test
    public void testMyBean() {
        RequestAttributes requestAttributes = new RequestAttributes();
        System.out.println(errorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, true));
    }

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "package.where.your.configuration.is")
    public static class SpringTestConfig {

    }
}
```

This test does a few things:

1. It leverages SpringRunner.class to create an ApplicationContext for you test.
2. The @ContextConfiguration annotation picks up the the static nested class SpringTestConfig. This class does the heavy lifting and actually scans base packages looking for other classes marked with Configuration, Bean, Component, etc. This will discover your Configuration which will in turn cause instantiation of your Bean.
3. Since the application context is now setup we can inject the bean with @Autowired as you would in normal application code.

I needed the following maven dependencies to accomplish this (junit >= 4.12 required). All are available in maven central:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```